# Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I want to run my **ionic app** in **android emulator**. When I try to build ionic app using the following command in terminal:

```
ionic build android
```

It shows the following error ::

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'.
      > Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

  * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 20.383 secs

 /home/meutics/ionicapp/ebook-   app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126

    throw e;
          ^
     Error code 1 for command: /home/meutics/ionicapp/ebook-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/meutics/ionicapp/ebook-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
```

Seems **JAVA_HOME** is not correctly configured, but I think I configure  **JAVA_HOME** correctly.

In **terminal** window, I run the following command ::

```
 meutics@meutics-pc:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

In **.bashrc** window,`vi ~/.bashrc`

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/home/meutics/Downloads/android-studio/bin
  export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
  export ANDROID_HOME=/home/meutics/Android/Sdk
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
```

How can I solve this problem?

NB: In `/usr/lib/jvm/` directory,

```
root@meutics-pc:/usr/lib/jvm# ls 
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64  java-8-oracle
```

And **java version** ::

```
   meutics@meutics-pc:$ java -version
   java version "1.8.0_60"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

just restart your CLI/ terminal and run as admin or do sudo on linux ... it worked for me